# Get buttons in frame

Tags: java, swing

I need to add a listener to each button like this:

```
 for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     buttons[i].addActionListener(actionListener);
```

The buttons already exist, and I need to get list of buttons in my frame.

Comment: Just create a `Button[]` and add each `Button` to it when you create they dynamically (or look up using the `R` class)

Comment: the buttons already exist,i need to get list of buttons in my frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `getComponents()` method to get all JButtons in the frame.

A working example:

```
frame = new JFrame();
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(250, 250);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
frame.setLayout(layout);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton("A"));

Component[] components = frame.getContentPane().getComponents();
ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
};

for (Component component : components)
{
    if (component instanceof JButton)
    {
        ((JButton) component).addActionListener(actionListener);
    }
}
```

It adds 10 buttons and then add the listener.

**Hint**: Don't do in this way if you create the buttons dinamically, its just overkill!

The above could be more simple:

```
frame = new JFrame();
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setSize(250, 250);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
frame.setLayout(layout);

ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
};

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    JButton button = new JButton("A");
    button.addActionListener(actionListener);
    frame.getContentPane().add(button);
}
```

Same code, without two fors!

But if you don't know how much Buttons you will have the first code would be ok, if you know and you just want to avoid an action before something happens, consider using a boolean variable.

Something like:

```
// out
boolean specialEvent;

// inside
ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (!specialEvent) return; // the special event is still false so no you can't do anything
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
};
```